# Limit users from pushing/pulling specific Docker images in AWS ECS Repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Is there a way to give users permission only to push/pull specific Docker images they own in AWS ECS Repo?

Answer (score 2):

By this time **you might have the solution**, but **sharing some info here**:

Consider **2 users with the following permissions**:

`ecr-user` with **policy ARN**:  `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess` who have **admin permissions for all resources in AWS**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

`vault-user` with **policy ARN** :`arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy` who has **limited permissions**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can **get this info from IAM->Users and click on the `Policy name` attached to the user**.

Consider below **2 repositories which are associated with users** `ecr-user` and `vault-user`

[image]

the repo `ecr-permissions` **is linked with** `ecr-user` with the following permissions:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "denyAdmin",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::****:user/ecr-user"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:ListImages",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:PutLifecyclePolicy",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So with the above policy, you can **even restrict admin user**(`ecr-user`) to push to this repo.

```
$ docker push ****.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ecr-permissions:1.0
The push refers to repository [****.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ecr-permissions]
fe6a7a3b3f27: Layer already exists 
d0673244f7d4: Layer already exists 
d8a33133e477: Layer already exists 
denied: User: arn:aws:iam::****:user/ecr-user is not authorized to perform: ecr:UploadLayerPart on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:****:repository/ecr-permissions with an explicit deny
```

Similarly, **you can allow non-admin/user[*in this case vault-user]* with read-only permission on ECR repo can push docker images** by tuning the ECR repo policies as shown below.

[image]

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "pushDocker",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::****:user/vault-user"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

> Before adding the above policy:

```
$ docker push ****.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/rlokinen/first-ecr:0.3
The push refers to repository [****.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/rlokinen/first-ecr]
fe6a7a3b3f27: Layer already exists 
d0673244f7d4: Layer already exists 
d8a33133e477: Layer already exists 
denied: User: arn:aws:iam::****:user/vault-user is not authorized to perform: ecr:InitiateLayerUpload on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:****:repository/rlokinen/first-ecr
```

> after adding the policy:

```
$ docker push ****.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/rlokinen/first-ecr:0.3
The push refers to repository [****.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/rlokinen/first-ecr]
fe6a7a3b3f27: Layer already exists 
d0673244f7d4: Layer already exists 
d8a33133e477: Layer already exists 
0.3: digest: sha256:dc85890ba9763fe38b178b337d4ccc802874afe3c02e6c98c304f65b08af958f size: 948
```

These **policies are defined per REPO in ECR**. `ECR->Repositories-><REPO-NAME>permissions`.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure IAM users within your account to push and pull images.

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPushPull",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::aws_account_id:user/push-pull-user-1",
          "arn:aws:iam::aws_account_id:user/push-pull-user-2"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Reference: [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/RepositoryPolicyExamples.html)

Comment: add conditions to this policy to further restrict users to push/pull specific images.

Comment: @Asdfg and Ashan, Thank you so much for your response. I am not sure where and how I can put the conditions to restrict/allow users to push/pull specific images. I would appreciate if you could show me an example.